# Update Using Entity Framework is not reflecting my DB table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web, entity-framework-6

I'm new to Entity Framework, and wrote a function to update a particular column `TStatus`.

Here is what I'm trying to execute:

```
public ActionResult UpdateTStatus(int ICCID) 
{
        using (var db = new MyDBContext())
        {
            var result = db.INTERVIEW_AGENT_CALL_CENTERS.Where(g => g.Id == ICCID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                result.TStatus= 10;
                db.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Content("Result = "+result.TStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("An Error");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Whenever I'm executing the method and run a direct query on SQL Server, I'm getting the old value of `TStatus`.

Comment: your update code looks correct. Are you passing Tstatus value 10 every time of different values?

Comment: No, 10 is a value just for a testing purpose

Comment: Can we see the `INTERVIEW_AGENT_CALL_CENTERS` class (and in particular, the `TStatus` field)? What is returned as the ActionResult - the `View()`, or `Content()`?

Comment: The issue was that I created the table INTERVIEW_AGENT_CALL_CENTERS in SQL Server but I didn't mapp it in edmx diagram in Visual Studio. That's why it wasn't inserting the value.
Thanks for your help :)